# Springboot Custom logout controller returns response 204

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I writed the following controller to logut a user:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth/api/access/login/")
public class SignoutController implements LogoutHandler
{        
 @GetMapping("signout")
 public ResponseEntity<String> viewlogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 {    
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); 
    this.logout(request, response, authentication); 
    return new ResponseEntity<>("signed-out", HttpStatus.OK);
 }  

@Override
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
{        
    if (authentication != null)
    {    
       new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, authentication);
    }     
  }
}
```

Testing the function with PostMan I obtain as response "204 no content".

Edit. Attempt after suggestion of answer #1. I removed the HttpServeletResponse from controller.I also tried to set the response within the logout method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth/api/access/login/")
public class SignoutController implements LogoutHandler
{        
 @GetMapping("signout")
 public ResponseEntity<String> viewlogout(HttpServletRequest request)
 {    
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); 
    this.logout(request, null, authentication); 
    return new ResponseEntity<>("signed-out", HttpStatus.OK);
 }  

@Override
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
{        
    if (authentication != null)
    {    
       new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, authentication);
    }     
 }
}
```

Comment: Right now, your logout endpoint is "/auth/api/access/loginsignout", maybe you wanted to set the GetMapping for "/signout"?

Comment: Do you mean that I forgot a "/" either in the @RequestMapping or in @GetMapping?

Comment: However, it should be added automatically. I have updated the code, the result is the same (204 no content)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by passing in `HttpServletResponse response` Spring uses that as your response, instead of the return value.

I would suggest either:

1. Set the status code manually:  `response.setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)`
2. Or remove the `HttpServletResponse` from the method signature and only pass in `null` to the security context `.logout(request, null, authentication)`.

Comment: Tried both approach unsuccessfully, I belive that SecurityContextLogoutHandler is configuring the response by itself.

Comment: It is not. You can check out the documentation or decompiled code. Only `request` parameter is used and the rest can be `null`.

Comment: I updated the question with the code I tried, may I missed something?

Comment: Additional note. The method is indicated in the SecurityFilterChain filterChain bean  as logoutURL. Removing it makes it work. Any idea why?

Comment: @Discipulos probably the SecurityFilterChain has its own implementation for basic logout. By defining it in filter chain, suddenly there are 2 different endpoints on the same path and the basic one had higher priority over the custom endpoint. Either way, you've found a solution. :)

Comment: What was the solution? I get this using the default logout. And a cors error on the client side.